# Hidden property when exporting JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to hide a text field using jasper report so when i will view it in html i wont see its content, but the problem is that it has to be there (proggram JAWS has to read it) so i can't use "printWhenExpression". I tried to use width properties to hide it but so far i have no effect.

```
        <textField>             
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Comment: `so i can't use "printWhenExpression"` -Why?

Comment: Because if i will use it it will just not print on the page. And i need it there it just have to be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need to keep the shape of the box as if the content was here, but you want the content to disappear.

It's true that `printWhenExpression` will make the whole item disappear.

You can either :

- **Use a parent item** such as a frame to be around the textField, so `printWhenExpression` is true on the text fields, then the frame will still be here to keep its place.

  ```
      <frame>
          <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" uuid="25b397bf-e718-43ab-8641-4f7c7932253f"/>
          <textField>
              <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="4e8ea258-88f0-4220-a350-448da63390d1">
                  <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[the_condition]]></printWhenExpression>
              </reportElement>
              <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
          </textField>
      </frame>
  ```
- Use a **java condition** in your text field. If the condition is false, the text will disappear but the text field frame will still be displayed.

  ```
      <textField>
          <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="4e8ea258-88f0-4220-a350-448da63390d1">
              <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[the_condition]]></printWhenExpression>
          </reportElement>
          <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[my_condition ? $V{PAGE_NUMBER} : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
  ```