# How to hide a particular row in croostab in jasper report by passing a value as true or false?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a croostab in which based on requirement I have to hide a particular row value. How can I do this?
Suppose there are 4 rows -

```
apple    bengaluru  5
samsung  delhi      7
vivo     mumbai     8
xiomi    chennai    6
```

Sometimes I have to hide the 2nd row and sometimes 3 or 4 based on passing a value true or false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printWhenExpression` attribute

To print the row only when the report parameter `myBoolean` is true :

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{myBoolean}]]></printWhenExpression>
```

If you want to hide it without removing its place from the page, see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281580/hidden-property-when-exporting-jasperreport/51379183#51379183)